# Improving boosting model ,reducing Root mean square error

Tags: machine-learning, boost, data-science, xgboost, hyperparameters

Hi i am solving a regression problem.My data set consists of 13 features and 550068 rows.I tried different different models and found that boosting algorithms(i.e xgboost,catboost,lightgbm) are performing well on that big data set.here is the code

```
import lightgbm as lgb
gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(objective='regression',num_leaves=100,learning_rate=0.2,n_estimators=1500)
gbm.fit(x_train, y_train,
    eval_set=[(x_test, y_test)],
    eval_metric='l2_root',
    early_stopping_rounds=10)
y_pred = gbm.predict(x_test, num_iteration=gbm.best_iteration_)
accuracy = round(gbm.score(x_train, y_train)*100,2)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)

import xgboost as xgb
boost_params = {'eval_metric': 'rmse'}
xgb0 = xgb.XGBRegressor(
max_depth=8,
learning_rate=0.1,
n_estimators=1500,
objective='reg:linear',
gamma=0,
min_child_weight=1,
subsample=1,
colsample_bytree=1,
scale_pos_weight=1,
seed=27,
**boost_params)
xgb0.fit(x_train,y_train)
accuracyxgboost = round(xgb0.score(x_train, y_train)*100,2)
predict_xgboost = xgb0.predict(x_test)
msexgboost = mean_squared_error(y_test,predict_xgboost)
rmsexgboost= np.sqrt(msexgboost)

from catboost import Pool, CatBoostRegressor
train_pool = Pool(x_train, y_train) 
cbm0 = CatBoostRegressor(rsm=0.8, depth=7, learning_rate=0.1, 
eval_metric='RMSE')
cbm0.fit(train_pool)
test_pool = Pool(x_test)
predict_cat = cbm0.predict(test_pool)
acc_cat = round(cbm0.score(x_train, y_train)*100,2)
msecat = mean_squared_error(y_test,predict_cat)
rmsecat = np.sqrt(msecat)
```

By using the above models i am getting rmse values about 2850.Now i want to improve my model performance by reducing root mean square error.How can i improve my model performance? As i am new to boosting algorithms,which parameters effect the models?And how can i do hyperparameter tuning for those algorithms(xgboost,catboost,lightgbm).I am using Windows10 os and intel i5 7th genration.

Comment: Understand your data and do feature engineering. It will reap in more rewards than trying different boosting techniques. Read kaggle winner interviews and all they have to say is do feature engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Out of those 3 tools that you have tried CatBoost provides an edge in categorical feature processing (it could be also faster, but I did not see a benchmark demonstrating it, and it seems to be not dominating on kaggle, so most likely it is not as quick as LightGBM, but I might be wrong in that hypothesis). So I would use it if I have many of those in my sample. The other two (LightGBM and XGBoost) provide very similar functionality and I would suggest to choose one of them and stick top it. At the moment it seems that **LightGBM outperforms XGBoost in training time on CPU** providing a very comparable precision of predictions. See for example [GBM-perf beachmark on github](https://github.com/szilard/GBM-perf) or [this in-depth analysis](https://sites.google.com/view/lauraepp/new-benchmarks). If you have GPU's available, than in fact XGBoost seems to be preferable, judging on the benachmark above.

In general, you can improve your model performance in several ways:

- train longer (if early stopping was not triggered, that means that there is still room for generalisation; if it was, then you can not improve further by training longer the chosen model with chosen hyper-parameters)
- optimise hyper-parameters (see below)
- choose a different model. There is no single silver bullet for all problems. Typically GBMs work very well on large samples of structured data, but for some classes of problems (e.g. linear dependence) it is hard for a GBM to learn how to generalise, as it might require very many splits. So it might be that for your problem a linear model, an SVM or something else will do better out of the box.

Since we narrowed down to 2 options, I can not advice on `catboost` hyper-parameter optimisation, as I have no hands-on experience with it yet. But for lightgbm tuning you can read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters-Tuning.rst) official lightgbm doc and [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/695) instructions in one of the issues. There are very many good examples of hyper parameter tuning for LightGBM. I can quickly dig out my kernel on kaggle: [see here](https://www.kaggle.com/mlisovyi/lightgbm-hyperparameter-optimisation-lb-0-746). I do not claim it to be perfect but that's something what is easy for me to find :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intel CPU, then try Intel XGBoost. Intel has powered several optimizations for XGBoost to accelerate gradient boosting models and improve its training and inference capabilities. Also, please check out the article, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/easy-introduction-xgboost-for-intel-architecture.html#gs.q4c6p6 on how to use XGBoost with Intel optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of lasso or ridge, these methods could improve the performance.

For hyper parameter tuning, you can use loops. iterate the values and check where you getting lowest RMSE values.

You can also try stacked ensemble techniques.

If you use R, use h20.ai package, It gives good result.

Comment: Yeah! i will try these methods.I am using python by the way.